# Exact quantiles instead or approximate ones in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, statistics

To calculate quantiles, I use `approxQuantile` method accessible from the `stat()` function in any `Dataset` or `Dataframe` of `Spark`. The way it approximate them [is explained by in this post](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/19/approximate-algorithms-in-apache-spark-hyperloglog-and-quantiles.html).

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Quantiles de la population communale française")
public void quantiles() throws TechniqueException {
   Dataset<Row> populationCommunes = individus().selectExpr("populationTotale");

   double[] quantiles = populationCommunes.stat().approxQuantile("populationTotale", new double[] {0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9}, 0);
   LOGGER.info("Population des communes françaises :\n Q(10%) : {}, Q(25%) = {}, Q(50%) = {}, Q(75%) = {}, Q(90%) = {}", 
      quantiles[0], quantiles[1], quantiles[2], quantiles[3], quantiles[4]); 
}
```

The results are reassuring :

```
Population des communes françaises :
 Q(10%) : 105.0, Q(25%) = 204.0, Q(50%) = 468.0, Q(75%) = 1186.0, Q(90%) = 3250.0
```

But if I really want to have the **exact** quantiles values, instead of approximate ones, how can I achieve that with `Spark` ?
Here, I have around 35,000 cities : I can gladly afford `Spark` to take the time to study each value of the `Dataset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `approxQuantile` function in Spark can be used to calculate exact quantiles. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameStatFunctions.html#approxQuantile-java.lang.String:A-double:A-double-) we see that there are 3 parameters:

> ```
> public double[][] approxQuantile(String[] cols, double[] probabilities, double relativeError)
> ```

with the last one being `relativeError`. The description here says:

> relativeError - The relative target precision to achieve (greater than or equal to 0). If set to zero, the exact quantiles are computed, which could be very expensive. Note that values greater than 1 are accepted but give the same result as 1.

So all you need to do is set this parameter to 0.0.